# Is it possible to click close button programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-access, dialog

I'm using a form as a dialog in Access, and I'm trying to figure out how to close it programmatically.
`DoCmd.Close` doesn't work here because it's opened as `acDialog`.

Is there a way to call the same event that gets triggered when a user clicks the close button?
If not, how can I close the form programmatically?

**Edit:**

To clarify, this is my form:

[image]

And this is the event:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    'DOES NOT WORK:
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form_Authentication Required"
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    'DOES NOT WORK EITHER:
    DoCmd.Close acDialog, "Form_Authentication Required"
End Sub
```

(The subs are not both in the code, they are just to illustrate the question)

Comment: It depends on what you're doing with that form. The code that opened the form is suspended but you could put an event on the form that closes it.

Comment: How would I put an event on the form?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to do with the form so I can't tell you what event to use but you just create a specific sub name in the form's code behind. If you want it timed you need to use ```Private Sub Form_Timer()``` and set an interval in form's property sheet in milliseconds. There are a lot of events so just find one that works with what you're doing.

Comment: Why would you even want to programmatically close a form and possibly interrupt user work?

Comment: @June7 It's a password form, and I'm trying to close it on cancel button click. Could be I'm being too long-winded but can't figure out an easier way

Comment: I am confused. A command button on dialog form can have DoCmd.Close and close itself.

Comment: The cancel button is a control that I created, not a generic command button

Comment: Still confused. I've never created custom controls but don't understand why it cannot call DoCmd.Close. Do you explicitly reference form by name to close? It is possible to call event procedure if the Private keyword is removed. Ex: `Forms!MyForm.MyButton_Click`. But I really don't see why that would be any more possible than directly calling DoCmd.Close.

Comment: DoCmd.Close doesn't work because it's a form that's opened in acDialog mode

Comment: The form in dialog can still run it's own code. It is the calling code that gets suspended.

Comment: I've clarified the question

Comment: Remove the "Form_" from the name in the ```docmd.close```

Comment: @Warcupine It worked. Next time I'll just post the code right at the start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for timeout of the form, you can study the function:

```vb
' Opens a modal form in non-dialogue mode to prevent dialogue borders to be displayed
' while simulating dialogue behaviour using Sleep.

' If TimeOut is negative, zero, or missing:
'   Form FormName waits forever.
' If TimeOut is positive:
'   Form FormName exits after TimeOut milliseconds.
'
' 2018-04-26. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function OpenFormDialog( _
    ByVal FormName As String, _
    Optional ByVal TimeOut As Long, _
    Optional ByVal OpenArgs As Variant = Null) _
    As Boolean
        
    Const SecondsPerDay     As Single = 86400
    
    Dim LaunchTime          As Date
    Dim CurrentTime         As Date
    Dim TimedOut            As Boolean
    Dim Index               As Integer
    Dim FormExists          As Boolean
    
    ' Check that form FormName exists.
    For Index = 0 To CurrentProject.AllForms.Count - 1
        If CurrentProject.AllForms(Index).Name = FormName Then
            FormExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If FormExists = True Then
        If CurrentProject.AllForms(FormName).IsLoaded = True Then
            ' Don't reopen the form should it already be loaded.
        Else
            ' Open modal form in non-dialogue mode to prevent dialogue borders to be displayed.
            DoCmd.OpenForm FormName, acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal, OpenArgs
        End If
        
        ' Record launch time and current time with 1/18 second resolution.
        LaunchTime = Date + CDate(Timer / SecondsPerDay)
        Do While CurrentProject.AllForms(FormName).IsLoaded
            ' Form FormName is open.
            ' Bring form to front; it may hide behind a popup form.
            DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, FormName
            ' Make sure form and form actions are rendered.
            DoEvents
        
            ' Halt Access for 1/20 second.
            ' This will typically cause a CPU load less than 1%.
            ' Looping faster will raise CPU load dramatically.
            Sleep 50
            If TimeOut > 0 Then
                ' Check for time-out.
                CurrentTime = Date + CDate(Timer / SecondsPerDay)
                If (CurrentTime - LaunchTime) * SecondsPerDay > TimeOut / 1000 Then
                    ' Time-out reached.
                    ' Close form FormName and exit.
                    DoCmd.Close acForm, FormName, acSaveNo
                    TimedOut = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        ' At this point, user or time-out has closed form FormName.
    End If
    
    ' Return True if the form was not found or was closed by user interaction.
    OpenFormDialog = Not TimedOut

End Function
```

It is taken from module *ModernBox.bas* from my project [VBA.ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox).

Comment: Wow, this is really cool! (Doesn't answer my question, but cool nonetheless) And it answers my as-yet-unasked question of how to remove the borders from a dialog form

Comment: In my project, look for the _InputMox_ function in the same module as above. It is close to your request.

Answer (score 1):

For a Close/Cancel button, always use

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

Using `Me.Name` will always work, even if you rename the form.

You may want to add

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
```

to avoid filters or sort order that the user has set, to be saved with the form.